# Replace all characters and first 0's (zeroes)

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace all characters inside a Regular Expression expect the number, but the number should not start with 0 
How can I achieve this using Regular Expression?

I have tried multiple things like `@"^([1-9]+)(0+)(\d*)"`and `"(?<=[1-9])0+"`, but those does not work

Some examples of the text could be `hej:\\\\0.0.0.22`, `hej:22`, `hej:\\\\?022` and `hej:\\\\?22`, and the result should in all places be `22`

Comment: Please add a sample text and what the output should be, it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: Have you considered writing a couple of simple lines of code that you know will work and which are easy to understand instead of struggling to concoct a regex that you will have trouble testing (and modifying in future if your requirements change)?

Comment: @JasonWilliams I have considered it, but I need a great performance.

Comment: @The87Boy regexes are not what performs best in general

Comment: this line The87Boy hej:\\\\?0222 wouldn't the results be 222

Comment: Yes, of course ;) A little typo

Comment: @The87Boy: THen drop regex and write something efficient that specifically targets your requirements.

Comment: please paste a small example of what the file or string really looks like.. this will also help others to under stand what you are looking for.. are there any delims in the file..?

Comment: What would the result be for `hej:\\\\0.011.0.022`? `1122` or `11022` or something else?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The answer should be `110022`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than replace, try and match against `[1-9][0-9]*$` on your string. Grab the matched text.

Note that as .NET regexes match Unicode number characters if you use `\d`, here the regex restricts what is matched to a simple character class instead.

(note: regex assumes matches at end of line only)

Comment: How do you match it recursively, cause it does not work with either Match or Matches

Comment: I don't know how to do this in C#, but also, you seem to always match at the end, do you mean you'll never have `xxx22xxxx`, for instance? Also, in `xxx202`, do you want `202` to be matched?

Comment: No I will never have that, cause it comes from a QR Code. Yes, in xxx202 I want 202 to be matched

Answer (score 1):

According to one of your comments `hej:\\\\0.011.0.022` should yield `110022`. First select the relevant string part from the first non zero digit up to the last number not being zero:

```
([1-9].*[1-9]\d*)|[1-9]
```

`[1-9]`       is the first non zero digit
`.*`             are any number of any characters
`[1-9]\d*` are numbers, starting at the first non-zero digit
`|[1-9]`     includes cases consisting of only one single non zero digit

Then remove all non digits (`\D`)

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([1-9].*[1-9]\d*)|[1-9]");
if (match.Success) {
    result = Regex.Replace(match.Value, "\D", "");
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
[1-9][0-9]*$
```

You don't need to do any recursion, just match that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you can try The87Boy you can play around with or add to the pattern as you like.

```
string strTargetString = @"hej:\\\\*?0222\";
string pattern = "[\\\\hej:0.?*]";
string replacement = " ";

Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
string newRegStr = Regex.Replace(regEx.Replace(strTargetString, replacement), @"\s+", " ");
```

`Result from the about Example = 22`